# How can I convert the following to VB.NET (Where Clause)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a legacy application that is is VB.NET and I need to convert this C# into VB.NET.  I don't know how to deal with the Where clause.  Can anyone help please.

```
ImageCodecInfo pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(codec => codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid)).FirstOrDefault();
if (pngCodec != null)
{
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8);
myImage.Save(myStream, pngCodec, parameters);
}
```

Comment: `Dim pngCodec As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(Function(codec) codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid)).FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer JQSOft.

Comment: Anytime bud. Good luck.

Comment: It's called a Lambda Expression so those are the keywords to search for if you need info on that.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Heard the expression but didn't connect the two.  I just couldn't work out the => bit

Comment: You can remove the `Where` part (not needed, in both languages) and just write: `Dim pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(Function(codec) codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid))`

Answer (score 0):

I hope , this should work:

```
 Dim pngCodec As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(Function(codec) codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid)).FirstOrDefault

 If Not pngCodec Is Nothing Then
     Dim parameters As New EncoderParameters
     parameters.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8)
     myImage.Save(myStream, pngCodec, parameters)
 End If
```